# How to execute WSL commands from a node process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, exec, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm developing a small node build script that I want to launch WSL, cd to my project directory, and invoke a build command. Something like this:

```
import { exec } from "child_process";

async function execCommand(cmd) {
  console.log("Executing: " + cmd);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) { reject(); }
      else { resolve(); }
    });
  });
}

await execCommand(`wsl`);
await execCommand(`cd /mnt/c/Users/Admin/Documents/Projects/myproject/backend`);
await execCommand(`cargo build --release`);
```

My issue is that it just.. doesn't work. That is, the first `execCommand` calls `wsl` and then the terminal window seems to never complete the command (it never finishes).

Instead, it prompts the user to type something in the command prompt.

What is the proper way to launch WSL from a node script and then chain a bunch of commands together, each one waiting on the previous one to finish?

Comment: Hi Ryan, `wsl --cd /mnt/c/Users/Admin/Documents/Projects/myproject/backend -e 'cargo build --release'` Try this command in a single `execCommand` instead,please.

Comment: @MattV Unfortunately the command prompt just says `Command failed` when I try that

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working.

Async version:

```
let child = spawn("wsl", [ "cd", "/mnt/c/Users/Admin/Documents/Projects/myserver/backend", "&&", "cargo", "build", "--release" ], {
  cwd: "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Projects\\myserver\\backend",
  shell: true
});

child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);

child.stdin.end();
```

Synchronous version:

```
let child = spawnSync("wsl", [ "cd", "/mnt/c/Users/Admin/Documents/Projects/myserver/backend", "&&", "cargo", "build", "--release" ], {
  cwd: "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Projects\\myserver\\backend",
  shell: true
});

console.log(child.stdout.toString());
console.log(child.stderr.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, my other answer isn't that good, because it launches a separate shell and runs the commands through the `cmd` shell instead, so the binary will be built by Windows instead of WSL, which is not what we want. A better answer is:

```
let child = spawnSync("wsl", [ "bash", "-l", "-c", "cargo build --release" ], {
  cwd: "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Projects\\myserver\\backend"
});

console.log(child.stdout.toString());
console.log(child.stderr.toString());
```

You need to include `bash -l` because when you run a command through `wsl` it doesn't execute `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` (etc). Cargo needs that so it can insert `~/.cargo/bin` to `$PATH`.

So with `bash -l` you force it to execute the profile init scripts. When you launch WSL without any other command, it will login interactively meaning those scripts are executed.